# ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, socketexception

I am using MySQL 5.1 and my connector version is mysql-connector-java-5.1.7. I am getting following exception frequently. What is the issue?

```
Dec 24, 2009 10:29:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve status
WARNING: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/error.jsp]
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:746)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:433)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:304)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:991)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:322)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: This does not look like it involves the MySQL connector....

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839314/clientabortexception-java-net-socketexception

Answer (score 0):

Going by the stacktrace, as Jim said ,it does not involve the MySql connector. Its tomcat closing the socket on its end for some reason while serving `error.jsp` to the client.You should check the server logs to zero in on the error.

Comment: I checked my server log in the folder Catalina_home/logs folder. But there is no error in the log file.

Comment: What are the contents of your error.jsp? Any code fragment which is prone to breaking down?

Comment: This is my error.jsp content

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Error Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <font face="Comic Sans MS" size=4>
   <h1><font color=red>404 Error Page</font></h1>
   <span>Sorry, you requested a page that does not exist.</span>
  </font>
 </body>
</html>