# Solr crashing with SocketException Broken pipe

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, indexing, tomcat6

I'm using Solr 3.1 with tomcat6. When the number of concurrent writes and reads increase it is crash throwing this SocketException error. I do concurrent commits and searches through multiple clients. Any kind of help is appreciated. Here is the tomcat log.

```
Dec 11, 2011 8:02:43 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:358)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:381)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:370)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastWriter.write(FastWriter.java:55)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeStr(JSONResponseWriter.java:622)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.StrField.write(StrField.java:54)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.write(SchemaField.java:130)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeDoc(JSONResponseWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeDoc(JSONResponseWriter.java:453)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeDocList(JSONResponseWriter.java:501)
        at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeNamedListAsMapWithDups(JSONResponseWriter.java:180)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeNamedList(JSONResponseWriter.java:296)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeResponse(JSONResponseWriter.java:93)
        at org.apache.solr.response.JSONResponseWriter.write(JSONResponseWriter.java:52)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:343)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:741)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:434)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:765)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:127)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:574)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
        ... 34 more
```

Comment: Why are you even doing concurrent commits (I assume to the same core)?

Comment: Also, the exception says the client disconnected (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839314/clientabortexception-java-net-socketexception ), so this seems to be a client issue, not a server (Solr/tomcat) problem... or a network problem.

Answer (score 1):

The exception suggests it's an unexpected client disconnection, so it's either a client issue or a network problem.

Related: [ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839314/clientabortexception-java-net-socketexception)

Answer (score 0):

I found that whenever my application timed out waiting on solr, I see this exception in the solr logs. For me solr was taking longer than 10 secs to process the query and the application waiting on it timed out.

Hope this helps