# Spring Boot 1.2.5 throws org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I'm running a Spring Boot web app (Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE) in Tomcat 8.0.26 as a standalone ROOT.war.

Environment: Java 8 u40, Windows 2008 Server R2.

I'm not sure why these exceptions appear in my logs randomly.

```
2015-09-23 15:14:36.796 [catalina-exec-1] ERROR o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for request [/login] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
        org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: 您的主机中的软件中止了一个已建立的连接。
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:342) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:110) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1039) ~[jackson-core-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:607) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:264) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:167) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:127) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:151) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.26]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: 您的主机中的软件中止了一个已建立的连接。
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:127) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:93) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:503) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.26]
        ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839314/clientabortexception-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-socket)

Comment: thank you for commit , i checked the application ,that might have tow spring context exists , since i packaged with spring-boot:repackage ,the exception has disappeared with a long time .