# HttpClient Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I used httpclient 4.4 to send get and post request. and i just created a simpile wrapper of httpclient for easy use:

```
    package com.u8.server.sdk;

    import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
    import com.u8.server.log.Log;
    import org.apache.http.Header;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpRequestRetryHandler;
    import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
    import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
    import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
    import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy;
    import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
    import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
    import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
    import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

    import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.CookiePolicy;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    /**
     * Created by ant on 2015/10/12.
     */
    public class UHttpAgent {

        private int connectTimeout = 5000;  //5s
        private int socketTimeout = 5000;   //5s
        private int maxTotalConnections = 200; 

        private static UHttpAgent instance;

        private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

        private UHttpAgent(){

        }

        public static UHttpAgent getInstance(){
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new UHttpAgent();

            }
            return instance;
        }

        public static UHttpAgent newInstance(){
            return new UHttpAgent();
        }


        public String get(String url, Map params){

            return get(url, null, params, "UTF-8");
        }


        public String post(String url, Map params){

            return post(url, null, params, "UTF-8");
        }


        public String get(String url , Map headers, Map params, String encoding){

            if(this.httpClient == null){
                init();
            }

            String fullUrl = url;
            String urlParams = parseGetParams(params, encoding);

            if (urlParams != null)
            {
                if (url.contains("?"))
                {
                    fullUrl = url + "&" + urlParams;
                }
                else
                {
                    fullUrl = url + "?" + urlParams;
                }
            }

            Log.d("the full url is "+ fullUrl);
            HttpGet getReq = new HttpGet(fullUrl.trim());
            getReq.setHeaders(parseHeaders(headers));
            ResponseHandler responseHandler = new ResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public String handleResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
                    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
                }
            };

            try {

                String res = httpClient.execute(getReq, responseHandler);

                return res;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                getReq.releaseConnection();
            }

            return null;
        }


        public String post(String url, Map headers, Map params, String encoding){

            List pairs = new ArrayList();
            if(params != null){

                for(String key : params.keySet()){
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, params.get(key)));
                }
            }

            return post(url, headers, new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, Charset.forName(encoding)));
        }


        public String post(String url, Map headers, HttpEntity entity){

            if(this.httpClient == null) {
                init();
            }

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeaders(parseHeaders(headers));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            ResponseHandler responseHandler = new ResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public String handleResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
                    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
                }
            };

            try {


                String body = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

                return body;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                httpPost.releaseConnection();
            }

            return null;

        }


        private Header[] parseHeaders(Map headers){
            if(null == headers || headers.isEmpty()){
                return getDefaultHeaders();
            }

            Header[] hs = new BasicHeader[headers.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for(String key : headers.keySet()){
                hs[i] = new BasicHeader(key, headers.get(key));
                i++;
            }

            return hs;
        }


        private Header[] getDefaultHeaders(){
            Header[] hs = new BasicHeader[2];
            hs[0] = new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            hs[1] = new BasicHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36");
            return hs;
        }


        private String parseGetParams(Map data, String encoding){
            if(data == null || data.size()  keyItor = data.keySet().iterator();
            while(keyItor.hasNext()){
                String key = keyItor.next();
                String val = data.get(key);

                try {
                    result.append(key).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(val, encoding).replace("+", "%2B")).append("&");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return result.deleteCharAt(result.length() - 1).toString();

        }


        private void init(){

            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                    .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)
                    .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
                    .setAuthenticationEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean retryRequest(IOException e, int retryNum, HttpContext httpContext) {

                    if(retryNum >= 3){
                        return false;
                    }


                    if(e instanceof org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
                            || e instanceof org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
                            || e instanceof java.net.SocketException){

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            };


            try{

                SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        return true;
                    }
                }).build();

                HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);

                Registry socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.create()
                        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                        .register("https", sslFactory)
                        .build();

                PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager( socketFactoryRegistry);
                connMgr.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConnections);
                connMgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute((connMgr.getMaxTotal()));

                HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom()
                        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                        .setSslcontext(sslContext)
                        .setConnectionManager(connMgr)
                        .setRetryHandler(retryHandler);

                this.httpClient = builder.build();


            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public HttpClient getHttpClient(){

            return this.httpClient;
        }

        public void destroy(){

            if(this.httpClient != null){
                try{
                    this.httpClient.close();
                    this.httpClient = null;
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

when I use this class to send post request. something strange happened:

the first time, I send a post request to the server, it's ok
after a minutes, I send a same request to the server, it's ok too.
but after a few minutes, I send a same request, something wrong:

```
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingOutputStream.write(LoggingOutputStream.java:77)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:138)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flush(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:146)
        at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.doFlush(BHttpConnectionBase.java:175)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.flush(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.flush(CPoolProxy.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:220)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139)
        at com.u8.server.sdk.UHttpAgent.post(UHttpAgent.java:259)
        at com.u8.server.sdk.UHttpAgent.post(UHttpAgent.java:147)
        at com.u8.server.sdk.baidu.BaiduSDK.verify(BaiduSDK.java:30)
        at com.u8.server.web.UserAction.getLoginToken(UserAction.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

but then , I still send a same request to the server, it's ok again.

Every time I tried according to the above steps, The same thing happened.

Anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is *not* a duplucate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839314/clientabortexception-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-socket That question is about a similar exception for a server (a servlet, specifically). This question is about a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peer of your client is the server. So "Connection reset by peer" means the server reset the socket. Reset means forceably closed.

This might be because of a bug in the server. If you also wrote the server or servlet (as will be the case for a custom protocol), you need to examine the behaviour of the server to examine the cause of this. The log files of the server might provide clues.

If the server has protection against bisbehaving or malicious clients,  the server might have reset the socket because it has classified your client as misbehaving. If you implemented the client protocol code it might be because of a bug in your protocol implementation. If you are using third party code for handling the communication protocol you might still be misusing it; for example by sending excessively large requests. It is not uncommon for HTTP servers to protect themselves against denial of service attacks by imposing maximum lengths for header fields and bodies, and to require that clients send data at a reasonably fast rate (without pausing for long periods). Your client might have fallen foul of these protections.

Comment: Or the server or servlet or its container, whatever the technology is, might be implementing an upload size or request size limit.